# Powershell: Update CSV at logon

Tags: powershell-4.0

I have a script that runs at logon that is implemented through group policies. This script scans for a particular file type and then passes that to a remove-item cmdlet. Once this is done the script should then be going to a network stored CSV and add a new row containing the computername and username of the currently running session. The problem here is that the search and destroy portion works great but the script never updates the CSV. The CSV has been setup with full control to everyone.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\ -Filter *.pst -force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Remove-Item –Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$Path = "\\corp-fs\Public\Alfa\Confirmation.csv"

$newLine = "{0},{1}" -f $env:COMPUTERNAME,$env:USERNAME | Add-Content -Path $Path
```

Any advice or help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer with a bit of research.

Startup scripts are run as the system account and cannot reach domain shares as they do not authenticate against the domain. These are also only applied to machine accounts in group policy management.

Logon scripts would work, however, they can only be applied to User accounts and not machine accounts. Doing this made the script run properly.